# how to align image inside a button using html and css?

Tags: html

```css
#button {
    background-color: rgb(211, 72, 54); /*i have aligned the text inside 
    the button but also need align the logo google+*/
    width: 35%;
    height: 6%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-left: 3%;
}
```

```html
<input id="button" type="button" value="Continue with Google" name="google" background-image: url(gmaillogo.png)>
```

I want the be left aligned in the button and vertically centered.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use background-image properly. You should use it in your CSS as follows:

Also, you have `background-size` (contain in this case will make the image fit in the parent) and `background-position`, which can be specified in pixels, percentages or keywords like left center etc. goinf

```css
#button {
    background-color: rgb(211, 72, 54); /*i have aligned the text inside 
    the button but also need align the logo google+*/
    width: 35%;
    height: 6%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left center;
    margin-left: 3%;
    background-size:contain;
    background-image:url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTFRki9RQJ1DJtL6gmwfWrTK4d3D6ozcPRHnryqQlY75_nwtCcdVPRSFw");
}
```

```html
<input id="button" type="button" value="Continue with Google" name="google" background-image: url(")>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#button {
  background-color: rgb(211, 72, 54);
  /*i have aligned the text inside 
    the button but also need align the logo google+*/
  width: 35%;
  height: 6%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-left: 3%;
  background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTFRki9RQJ1DJtL6gmwfWrTK4d3D6ozcPRHnryqQlY75_nwtCcdVPRSFw);
  background-position: left center;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<input id="button" type="button" value="Continue with Google" name="google" />
```